# How did humans reach the rim in RimWorld?

Tags: rimworld

According to the [RimWorld Lore](https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Lore) page:

1. There are no naturally occurring alien civs
2. There is no faster-than-light travel
3. The date of the game setting is 5500 A.D. (3.5k years from now being the important corollary)
4. There are habited planets near the core and — obviously — near the rim

Estimates I've seen say that we are about 25k lightyears from the core and "rim".

So my question is how did humans even make one trip from Earth to the rim (let alone from the core to the rim)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the term “rim”.  The document you linked says:

> The best historians of the Ordo Historia believe that humanity first
> left its origin planet Earth about 3,400 years ago. Since then, we’ve
> spread across the galaxy on a fitful wavefront of colony ships,
> frontier worlds, robotic terraforming projects, and DNA-synthesizing
> probes.
>
> Today, mankind is smeared across a region of the galaxy about 1,200
> light years wide. Our best models indicate that there is a general
> trend towards greater population density towards the center of the
> this region, where the stars were colonized earlier. **At the edge of
> known space lie the rimworlds**, drifting alone with few inhabited
> neighbors, mostly unvisited.

Also:

> Rimworlds: Planets lacking in strong central government and low in
> population density. These places tend to hover around the industrial
> level of technology or lower. Because they’re not homogenized by a
> central government, they tend to see a lot of interaction between
> people of different technology levels, as travelers crashland or
> ancient communities stumble out of their cryptosleep vaults. These
> planets are often at the **rim of known space**, hence the name.

They’re talking about the rim of known space, not the rim of the galaxy.

Comment: If you take the phrase literally, the “rim of known space” is about 50 _billion_ light years away, isn’t it? I’m guessing that that phrase is meant to be interpreted as “the rim of _human-inhabited_ space.”

Comment: @TannerSwett: We know *of* that space, but we haven't been there so you could argue we don't really *know* it.  In an SF context, "known space" was used exactly this way by Larry Niven to describe the setting for several of his short stories and novels (including Ringworld), https://larryniven.fandom.com/wiki/Known_Space - "*Known Space is a volume of interstellar space **explored** by humans and their alien neighbors.*"  Rimworld is a different setting, but it's in-universe use of the term "known space" to describe the explored/settled area was likely inspired by Niven.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Not to mention Rimworld vs Ringworld.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the fictional setting, but I believe this question is answerable purely in terms of science. As I read it, I think your question is presupposing either (or both) a meaningful absolute sense of time or that traveling N lightyears takes more than N years. Neither of these is actually the case, thanks to relativity.

At 1g constant acceleration, a trip of 25 thousand lightyears can be made in just a few years, from the reference frame of those making the trip. Of course, from the reference frame of the starting point, it will take over 25 thousand years.

So, when you speak of 5500 AD, you need to clarify whether it's Earth's reference frame or the reference frame of some "rim world". I'm guessing it's the latter, in which case it's probably more like 30000 on Earth.

If you want the trip to be made slowly enough that the that the times remain close, then indeed there's no way to get that far in 3500 years. But maybe it's possible if the distance is lower.

Wikipedia's article on [Space travel under constant acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_travel_under_constant_acceleration) may help to clarify this. I recall there being more detailed material on the subject on one or more of the Stack Exchange sister sites (maybe space or physics).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do note however that answers based on in-universe evidence are much preferred to answers based on real world science, which doesn't necessarily apply in a fictional setting.

Comment: @LogicDictates: Yeah, I gathered that, but I think it's relevant since the question as asked seems to indicate that the fictional setting is aiming to be compatible with science (no FTL).

Comment: Questions asking for answers based on real world science are off-topic here, so even if that's the sort of answer the querent was looking for (which it may not be), you shouldn't provide one, as you'd be rewarding them for posting an off-topic question, and incentivising more questions in that vein.

Comment: Nothing like being welcomed to a new SE site by a deletion warrior...

Comment: You are welcome here, and I haven't downvoted your answer or flagged it for deletion. I'm just explaining the rules and practices of site to you, as I understand them.

Comment: There's an existing answer quoting in-universe statements that "Today, mankind is smeared across a region of the galaxy about 1,200 light years ... At the edge of known space lie the rimworlds".  So there's no need to try to interpret 5500 A.D. as a subjective time or Earth-light-cone time, or to explain a distance larger than what's actually in-universe.  It would be possible to do so this way, in a hypothetical setting that did work that way, but I don't think this makes a good answer to *this* question about the Rimworld setting.

Comment: @LogicDictates: What actually made me feel unwelcome was your reaction to my answer with a suggestion of policing what OP might be "looking for" despite the question as asked being perfectly reasonable. Not any downvoting or deletion of my answer, but suggesting that my answer, if relevant, would be motivation for declaring OP's question subject to deletion.

Comment: @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE - I don't think there's any danger of this question being closed, as it isn't explicitly seeking an answer based on real world science. Rather, it seems to be asking how that journey was possible _in-universe_. But in principle, if this question were focused on real world science rather than in-universe science, then it would be off-topic here, and subject to closure. We're also discouraged from answering off-topic questions, so as not to invite more of them.